# Constant graphs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I need to graph $1 \over d^2$ with average light intensity, where $d$ is $5,10,15,20,25,30$ (i.e. squared would be equal to $1\over25$$1\over100$$1\over225$$1\over400$$1\over625$$1\over900$). The average light intensity would be 766,217,90,50,29,21 respectively (i.e. 766 would be for 5, and 217 would be for 10, etc..)

The graph should look like a constant line just like this but obviously for different x and y variables.

[image]

I'm stuck on how to draw the line graph in a way that shows a constant.

Comment: ?????????? A *constant* is an *horizontal* line.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I mean a graph that is basically like the one I showed.

Comment: I have plotted it once using a hyperbola, but now I need to do a 1^d2 graph in the form of a line like above,

Answer (score 1):

After a very few attempts but very much guided by your underlying ideas, I effectively found that the reciprocal of the square root of the average light intensity varies linearly with $d$; its is almost perfect (I guess and hope) for your plot requirement.

So, you keep $d$ for the $x$ axis and you change what was $y$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$. The least square regression gives you a slope which is $0.007234$ and no intercept since you did not want any.

Comment: If you could show or do that for me, I understand what you are trying to say but don't know how to do it. There is a simpler way involving finding the line of best fit I think

Comment: In other words, the best line fit using your original data is $y=b/d^2$ with $b=19311.4$ from ordinary least square method. Then, manipulate and you arrive to what I answered. Is this better now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try in http://people.hofstra.edu/Stefan_Waner/newgraph/regressionframes.html with the data:

0.04    766

0.01    217

0.0044  90

0.0025  50

0.0016  29

0.0011  21